# Can AutoCAD entities be serialized?

Tags: c++, autocad, objectarx

Using ObjectARX (C++) for AutoCAD 2010, can AutoCAD entities be serialized?

We need to save the serialized entity in a field in a database (Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc., not AcDbDatabase).  It'OK if you show me how to save them in disk, something like this:

```
AcDbEntity * entity;
...
std::ofstream ofs("c:\\filename.fil", std::ios::binary);
ofs.write((char *)(entity), sizeof(entity));
ofs.close();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "no". AutoCAD database objects include references to other objects, so you can't deserialize discrete objects without also ensuring the presence of all referenced objects.

Technically, what you describe can be done for an entire hierarchy of interconnected objects by implementing a custom AcDbDwgFiler that includes the necessary inter-object reference management infrastructure, then serializing the objects to the filer via AcDbObject::dwgOut() and deserializing them via AcDbObject::dwgIn(). But you end up essentially duplicating what AutoCAD already does when serializing an entire database to a .dwg file, so it defeats the purpose in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Owen, but there may be another solution if you do not want to save your data in dwg file. 
Notice that ObjectArx surpport MFC, MFC has its own serialize mechanism. you can derive your entity from both AcDbEntity and MFC CObject. Use mechanism of MFC to serialize your data.
If you overide MFC's serialize methods, you can easily serialize the data into database.
To do this, you have to call MFC serialize funcntions inside dwgin and dwgout.